# Salesforce communities Site.login

Tags: community

I've created a custom login page that use the 'Site.login' function.
The problem I'm facing is that function always returns null.

Running this code always returns null:

system.debug(Site.login('myEmail', 'myPassword', null));

Please advice.

Comment: Does anyone can help with that? Thanks!